# Combinging rules in Regex

Tags: php, regex

Trying to write a rule for a WP redirect

I've got the rule `^((?!json).)*$`

Which ignores:

- /wp-json/aber

And the rule `^([^.\?]*[^\/])$`

Which ignores:

- /aber.css
- /france?foobar=1

But I can't seem to figure out how t combine them into a single rule that ignores all three. if I add [^.?|json] if rules out any URLs including any of those characters individually. It only needs to be exactly "json" located anywhere in the URL or URLs that include a . or a ?

### Examples:

Dont match:

- /wp-json/aberdeen
- /aberdeen.css
- /aberdeen?foobar=1

Match:

- /wp-jsn/aberdeen
- /aberdeen

Comment: You could skip the line that contains `json` and then match non whitespace chars except `.` and `?` and rule out `/` at the end `^\S*?\bjson\b.*$(*SKIP)(*F)|^[^\s.?]+$(?<!\/)` https://regex101.com/r/h1CYZB/1

Comment: Not sure how skipping lines solves it, it needs to work with any input and ignore any URLs that might include the text json and the data will not be provide in a line format

Comment: But you want to match either the whole line or not right?

Comment: Apologies maybe I misunderstood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the first pattern `^((?!json).)*$` simply asserts that `json` does not appear anywhere in the input.  We can refactor the second pattern by adding a negative lookahead to rule out `json`:

```
^(?!.*json)([^.\?]*[^\/])$
```

Comment: According to this Regex tester it's still not ignoring json https://regexr.com/77s5g

Comment: @GibsonFX According to [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/9utNEA/) it is working.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/56Ni68/1 but it isn't here when I add more examples

Comment: Okay just seems it was having issue with the text above for some reason, sorry thank you

Comment: I guess that's why I've been banging my head against the wall for the 2 hours with this lol

Comment: I have also seen such weird behavior before with regex demo tools.

Comment: @GibsonFX  I believe the issue is with it being multi-line and having multiple test lines.  In your example on Regex101 if you remove the line return after "Don't Match"   Or if you just remove that and the line return, then it works as expected.  Adding the "s" flag with the "m" will also fix the issue.  So `gsm` for the flags.